# A function between covering spaces.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Given $p_1:\bar X_1\rightarrow X$ and $p_2:\bar X_2\rightarrow X$ covering maps. Proof that if exist $f:\bar X_1\rightarrow \bar X_2$ continuos and surjective then $f$ is a covering map.

I don't know how to find the open set that are evenly covered by $f$.

Any hint?

Comment: What is your definition of covering map?

Comment: It's not true without some kind of compabiliity between $f$, $p_1$, and $p_2$.  For a family of counterexamples, let $X_1 = X_2 = X$ be any space which admits a surjective continuous non-covering map $f$ and let $p_1 = p_2 = Id_X$.  For a concrete example, let $X = \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = x^3 - x$  This isn't a covering as $f^{-1}(0) = \{-1,0,1\}$, so $0$ three preimages, but $100$ only has one.  If I had to guess, the assumption $p_1 = p_2\circ f$ should make it work.

Comment: The proof is technical. You can find it in Munkres' *Topology*, Lemma 80.2, for instance.